# Data Migration. Pulling Select statements into constants. Having problems with using non static fields in static members

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am performing data migration as an assignment.  I am supposed to pull out Select Statements into a constant

```
public static String Name = "SELECT column FROM table";
```

**Problem :** My problem is that in the select statement there is a non static variable passed into it from the JAVA code.

```
"c.characid in (select characid from tr_charac where name='" + TRBaseSql.rewrapQuotes(characName) + "')"
```

So when i pull this into my constant it says.

```
public static String NEWQUERY = "select characid from tr_charac where name='" +TRBaseSql.rewrapQuotes(characName) + "')"
```

It tells me that `characid` has not been defined yet, probably because the NEW constant is static and defined at runtime.

How should I get this to work with my query?

Comment: characid is the one in question.

Comment: It tells me that characid has not been defined yet, probably because the NEW constant is static and defined at runtime.